# SQL where date column bigger than other date column by atleast 20 days

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm having difficulty finding rows in my Table where two date columns have a difference of at least 20 days between them (no specific date is required, just 20 days difference)

I tried this with no luck:

```
SELECT DocDate,DocDueDate,DocStatus
FROM dbo.OPCH
WHERE (DocDate - DocDueDate = 20) AND DocStatus = 'O' AND DocDate > '2014-01-01'
```

This doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Removed mysql tag because syntax is SQL Server.

Comment: If you want at least 20 days, then you don't want an equal sign, you want a greater than or equal to sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dates are actually declared as `datetime`, you can do:

```
SELECT DocDate,DocDueDate,DocStatus
FROM dbo.OPCH
WHERE (DocDate >= DocDueDate + 20) AND DocStatus = 'O' AND DocDate > '2014-01-01';
```

Adding a number to a date time is interpreted as adding that number of days.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work for `date`.

For `date`, you can do:

```
WHERE datediff(day, DocDueDate, DocDate) >= 20 AND DocStatus = 'O' AND DocDate > '2014-01-01'
```